# XPath for labeled text value?

Tags: xml, xpath

What XPath I need to extract the text inside `b` that is found inside a `li` with a specific label?

Example code:

```
<li>Job category:<b>Engineering</b></li>
<li>Job Type:<b>Full Time</b></li>
```

Example page: http://tiruvallur.click.in/job-vacancy-in-uk-needed-engineers-send-your-cv-c98-v15807437

Comment: I have NOT undo the changes, I just added 1 more row, why you deleted it? Sorry for being unclear from first time, I am new in this forum and is the first time I see an admin editing my question.

Comment: I'm not an admin, just an experienced user with editing privileges trying to make the site better for current and future readers.  Please feel free to adjust my edits; it's your question.  I just ask that you not reject them all out-of-hand without understanding why I made them.

Comment: Let's get back to the substance of your question.  If you share exactly how you used the suggested answers and what results (including specific errors) you received, we should be able to resolve your impasse.  It may help you to know that the two XPaths I provided have been tested both against your samples (wrapped in a common root element) and in all cases worked as requested.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression

```
string(//li[starts-with(., 'Job Type:')]/b)
```

will select

```
Full Time
```

for your example.

Alternatively, and possibly more robustly, you might take the substring after the label on the string value of the `li`

```
substring-after(//li[starts-with(., 'Job Type:')], 'Job Type:')
```

will also select the same string

```
Full Time
```

To eliminate spurious whitespace, use `normalize-space()`:

```
normalize-space(substring-after(//li[starts-with(., 'Job Type:')], 'Job Type:'))
```

Comment: Your XPATH does not extract anything from this website

Comment: Both XPath's I've provided do work both on your examples and on the webpage linked to in your question.   The web page actually has more whitespace, but you can fix that easily enough with `normalize-space()`.  Answer updated.  Other than that, if it's not working for you, you're making some other mistake along the way.  Double check your work, and/or post exactly what you're doing so we can help you check it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this:** //*[contains(text(),'*your-label-name*')]/b/text()

**For ex:**

```
  //*[contains(text(),'Job category')]/b/text()
```

Comment: Your XPATH does not extract anything from this website

Comment: I don't know what trouble you are facing, give me some screenshots of your code. I have tried the above and working fine. You can see the following snip:: [image](https://s26.postimg.org/y0h8kc47d/xpath.png)

Comment: I am using www.import.io software and your XPATH does not extract anything even it if appears to work in Firefox. After multiple attempts I found an XPATH that does extract the data: //li[contains (.,"Job Type")]/b